# Saving and querying areas in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geocoding

I have a series of areas (cities, districts, etc) saved in a MySQL DB. At the moment these contain only out of a human readable name.

How can I select all records that contain a particular lat/long point? How can I save the area information? Is a tie-in with the Google Maps API possible?

(And yes, unfortunately, I am tied to using MySQL.)

Comment: you can download geo location database from http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country,
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/   and make use of it

Answer (score 0):

Your best off doing something like using the Google API to gather the lat and long of a given postcode ( assuming you have postcodes ) and building up and object of all the lat/longs/postcodes then write PHP script/function to then just loop through the array updating your database records by the postcode with the new lat and longs

for example:

```
$data = array ( array ( 'e11', '0.01111', '5.313133' ), array ( 'e11', '0.01111', '5.313133' ) );

foreach ( $data as $p )
{
   query ( 'UPDATE table SET lat = "' . $p['lat'] . '", lng = "' . $p['long'] . '" WHERE postcode = "' . $p['postcode'] . '" );
}
```

It's just long winded to then gather up all them long lats and put in a format to actually loop through.

Comment: It is not so much a problem of finding a lat/long, but saving an area. Same problem for postcodes: They are represented by polygons not points.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy to do in vanilla MySQL.  Most of the time people solve this problem by using GIS extensions to their database engine to let you store the type of "area" information you're looking for.  MySQL has [Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) which should do the trick, the exact functions you are probably looking for, like ST_Contains are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html).

**Note:** You need to have MySQL >= 5.6.1 to get the intended behavior from the `contains` function, otherwise they're just dumb rectangle based operations.